# Return all records where a field has the same prefix

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a PromoID field in a table. I need to figure out how to display all records where the first 6 charactes are the same:

```
PromoID
=======
100001
100001A
100001B
101001
100002
100002A
```

The result I would expect to see from the above would be:

```
PromoID
=======
100001
100001A
100001B
100002
100002A
```

101001 gets excised as it doesn't have another record with the "101001" prefix.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT PromoID
FROM YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT LEFT(PromoID,6)
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE LEFT(PromoID,6) = LEFT(A.PromoID,6)
             GROUP BY LEFT(PromoID,6)
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

This are the results:

```
╔═════════╗
║ PromoID ║
╠═════════╣
║ 100001  ║
║ 100001A ║
║ 100001B ║
║ 100002  ║
║ 100002A ║
╚═════════╝
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c43b1/1) an sqlfiddle with a demo.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, this should work for you:

```
SELECT PromoID
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(PromoID, 6)) AS cnt
  FROM atable
) s
WHERE cnt > 1
;
```

You can try this [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a4b2/1) too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using a subselect

```
SELECT PromoID FROM YourTable
WHERE LEFT(PromoID,6) IN
(
SELECT LEFT(PromoID,6) 
FROM YourTable 
Group By LEFT(PromoID, 6)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c43b1/10)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH CTE (Prefix) AS
  (select LEFT(PromoId, 6) from Foo GROUP BY LEFT(PromoId, 6) HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
SELECT PromoId FROM Foo
INNER JOIN CTE ON LEFT(PromoId, 6) = CTE.Prefix;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84081/5)

Comment: This way op will have only the truncated part of the column, and not the result that s/he wants

Answer (score 0):

The inner query lists all PromoID to reject. The outer query takes all PromoID minus the rejected ones:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE PromoID not in (
    SELECT t1.PromoID
      FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.PromoID != t2.PromoID
          AND left(t1.PromoID, 6) = left(t2.PromoID, 6)
     WHERE t2.PromoID IS NULL
 )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/063f1/19)